# How to save data form multiple textboxes to file(.txt) in C#?

Tags: c#

```
private void AddUserSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream AddUserData = new FileStream("AddUser.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            using (StreamWriter AddUserDataWrite = new StreamWriter(AddUserData))
            {
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(DisplayNameTextBox + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(UserNameTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(PasswordTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(ConfirmPasswordTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(DepartmentComboBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(DesignationTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(BasicSalaryTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(JoiningDateDateTimePicker.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(AgreeRadioButton.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(FirstNameTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(LastNameTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(FatherNameTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(MaleRadioButton.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(FemaleRadioButton.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(CNICNumberTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(ContactNumberTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(EmailAddressTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(DOBDateTimePicker.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(ResidentialAddressTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(CityTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
                AddUserDataWrite.Write(CountryTextBox.Text + "\r\n");
            }                                    
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
        }
    }
```

This is code of a Registration form. When I enter data and click the submit button all the data in textboxes saves to file "AddUser.txt" but when I enter data second time and click submit button the data overwrites to same file "AddUser.txt".

Simply, I want create new .txt file every time when I click submit button so that data of each person saves to individual .txt file.

Is there any way?

Comment: You have to be more specific if you want to get any help from here. What did you already try? What is your approach? Example code? etc.

Comment: Please can u tell me how to use textbox in loop ?

Comment: Specify your question and provide the code you ware using. Otherwise nobody can really help you.

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look  at http://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox for getting data from the textboxes.

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx to save your data to file.

Comment: Please can u tell me how to use textbox in loop ?

Comment: That should be something like:


`foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{               
        if (c.GetType().Name.ToString()=="TextBox")
       {
               /// Do Something
       }
}`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You have to define what combination of the input values makes the person unique. I assume that the username makes a person unique, so maybe this could be the solution:

```
 var filename = string.Format("AddUser_{0}.txt", UserNameTextBox.Text);
 FileStream AddUserData = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
 // code for wrting the information comes here (as you already have in your code)
```

This will create a seperate file for each user. If a user chooses a username that already exists, the previous file will be overwritten. So make sure you use a unique combination of user attributes for the filename.

**Solution 2:**

There is another solution, where you use a generated unique id to make unique filenames. Just add a UID to the filename instead of the username or so. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx